# Test decorated Mongoose Schema with TypeScript and jest

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I am learning MongoDb and jest. I have the following mongoose schema built with typescript decorators and I want to make sure that fields get validated by schema.

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    match: /^[A-Za-z]$/,
  })
  firstName: string;
}

export type UserDocument = User & Document;
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

and I want to write unit tests for the schema with jest.

```
import { User, UserDocument, UserSchema } from '../user.schema';

describe('User', () => {
  let user: UserDocument;

  beforeEach(() => {
    user = new User() as UserDocument;
  });

  describe('firstName', () => {
    it('should contain only english letters', async () => {
      user.firstName = 'J0hn';
     // I must validate the schema
     const error = await user.validate();
     expect(error).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

But I got an error: `.validate is not a function`;
How can I perform this test?

Comment: There's no `validate` method for the `User` class, right? Where would that come from?

Comment: I want to get Model in my test, but I don't know where. Unfortunately, across the internet there is only way to mock the model, for example, in service test :/

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: n the `User` class that you define above, where does the `validate` method exist? It doesn't, does it? You're wanting to test against the mongoose Model, so you need to use the exported schema, not the class

Comment: so you want me to import that UserSchema and test via it? Because that doesn't have validate method. I need to test actual Model, but I am not able to get it. The Mongoose Model is created in MongooseModule.forFeature(...). I should mock connection to the db, so I cannot just get the Model from TestingModule.

Comment: Then you'll need to actually connect wth a database, get the model out of the mongoose connection, and _then_ test the `validate` method